# drupal error-Image API requires that an image toolkit be enabled before it will work! Please enable an image toolkit on the modules page

Tags: drupal-modules

when working with drupal an error message shows like this "Image API requires that an image toolkit be enabled before it will work! Please enable an image toolkit on the modules page."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this in the module's source (`imageapi.install`)

*ImageAPI requires a Toolkit such as ImageAPI [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php) or ImageAPI [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.imagick.php) to function*

You should check your php libraries.